# How to set a maximum sell limitation for token per transaction/24 hours on a ECR20 token

Tags: solidity, blockchain, ether, metamask

How to set limitations for token-sale in solidity. for example, 1 account can buy 1000 tokens per day. now I set a limit for one transaction. here i displayed my code

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract HelioToken {

                
        uint256 public totalSupply;

        event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint256 _value
        );

        event Approval(
        address indexed _owner,
        address indexed _spender,
        uint256 _value
    );

        mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
        mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

        constructor(uint256 _initialSupply) {
                balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
                totalSupply = _initialSupply;
        }

        function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
        require(_value >= 1000);
        
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);

        return true;
        }

        function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;

        emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);

        return true;
        }

        function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);

        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;

        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;

        emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to track it daily at a certain time or every 24h?!

Comment: @AhmadGorji yes. you are correct.